# How to cluster standard errors using Stata's stcrprep

Tags: stata, survival-analysis

I am using Stata to model cumulative incidence functions in the presence of competing risks. Each spell ends with the occurrence of an event ("failure"), but subjects have the possibility of entering a new spell afterwards. Hence the spells are not independent, but nested in the subjects.

The standard Stata command stcrreg can handle this structure by modelling standard errors that are clustered at the subject-level. However, my dataset is huge (over 3 million observations) and the computation time is enormous. Other users have suggested using the user-written program stcrprep, which also enjoys additional features.

Does anyone know how to cluster standard errors using stcrprep?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution from the information available in the help file of `stcrprep` and explained in a presentation by the writer of the command (http://repec.org/usug2013/lambert.uk13.pdf).

Clustered standard errors can be easily achieved as follows.

1. Prepare the data for survival analysis using `stcrprep`.
2. Create the right format using `stset`, specifying weights as pweights. Specifying them as iweights would make estimation of robust and cluster-robust standard errors impossible.
3. Conduct the competing-risks regression using `stcox` and specify the desired `,vce()` option. Note that through this way of data preparation, this will produce exactly the same results as `stcrreg`.

For the interested reader, an example of estimating the risk of cancer in the presence of competing cardiovascular diseases and other causes of death, with censored observations, and patients clustered in therapy:

```
use "http://www.stata-journal.com/software/sj4-2/st0059/prostatecancer", clear
stset time, failure(status=1,2,3) id(id) //specify all possible events
stcrprep, events(status) keep(treatment age therapy) trans(1) //trans creates failcode (event of interest)
gen event = failcode == status
stset tstop [pw=weight_c], failure(event==1) enter(tstart)
stcox treatment age, vce(cluster therapy)
```